# Maintain ratio between two d3.js graphs

Tags: javascript, d3.js, responsive-design

I created a graph (based on this block https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1667367) on a resizable container. The problem is that when I resize the container, if the container is at a certain height, both graphs overlap. The ideia is to maintain the ratio and distance between the two graphs, whatever the size of the container is. Any ideas?

Code: http://pastebin.com/DJqYbe6G

Comment: Can you paste the working code in a fiddle or codepen?

Comment: Well, this is an angular project, it needs some code to make this run in a fiddle. If you need, the block I put is enough, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Nailed it. It seems the combination between AngularJS and D3 give a hard time to access the `svg` elements. By accessing the parent graph height we can maintain a ratio between him and the child graph:

```
var parentHeigtht = angular.element($elem[0])[0].parentNode.clientHeight;

var margin = {top: 20, right: 10, bottom: 220, left: 40},
margin2 = {top: parentHeigtht-150, right: 10, bottom: 60, left: 40},
width = ($elem[0].parentNode.clientWidth) - margin.left - margin.right,
height = ($elem[0].parentNode.clientHeight) - (margin.top) - (margin.bottom),
height2 = ($elem[0].parentNode.clientHeight) - (margin2.top) - (margin2.bottom);
```